# What is the difference between cleaning and cleansing?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder what the difference is between cleaning and cleansing solutions. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8):

I would say that "cleaning" normally involves removing dirt and blemishes from the surfaces of an object, while "cleansing" refers to removing impurities from the object as a whole.

To borrow one of @Damkerng's examples, an herbal remedy may claim to "cleanse the body, removing harmful toxins"; I would take that to mean that if I ingest it, it will eliminate said toxins from my innards.  If the herbal remedy claimed only to "clean your body, removing harmful toxins", I would interpret that as something to put in my bath so that my skin no longer has harmful toxins clinging to it; a much less powerful statement.

Similarly, a product that *cleans* my skin may leave it with no dirt but all the pimples, warts, corns, age-spots, and wrinkles that were always there.  A product that *cleanses* my skin should at the very least be eliminating all of the conditions that would normally cause pimples, warts, etc. to start forming (blocked glands, build-up of dead skin cells, etc.), if not actually eliminating the blemishes themselves.

Answer (score 6):

Both ***clean*** and ***cleanse*** have a similar meaning: ***to make something or someone clean***. Even Merriam-Webster Dictionary gives the definition of *[cleanse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleanse)* as "clean".

Personally, when someone uses the word *cleanse*, it usually means something beyond just *clean*. I usually take it as ***to make it pure*** or ***to make it clear***. Here are things that I usually found the word *cleanse* is more preferred: *cleanse your face* (as in *cleansing lotions* or *cleansing solutions* in the OP's question), *cleanse your soul*, and *data cleansing*.

Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary gives more details on the usage of **[cleanse](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cleanse)**.

> **usage** The verbs *clean* and *cleanse* both mean “to make (something or someone) clean.” Cleanse usually refers to making the body or part of the body clean.
>   ▪ *cleansing* the skin ▪ The herb is believed to *cleanse* the body of toxins. It can also refer to making a person's mind, soul, reputation, etc., clean. ▪ The ceremony is meant to *cleanse* people of their guilt and sin. ▪ Try to *cleanse* your mind through meditation. *Clean* is more common than *cleanse* and its use is less specific.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning is removing dirt from an external surface for example cleaning your house whilst cleansing is removing dirt from an internal surface  for example data cleansing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Please provide reliable references for the information you are giving.